# Div Overlapping incorrectly

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I am trying to implement a menu into an area.

http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk/newhomepage

You will see the end of the menu div slightly off the page to the right, however this needs to be inside the HOMEMENU section (the long black bar with no content)

It seems to be overflowing into other areas, despite using a clear:both div.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Is it a z-index issue or something more simple?

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do. Could you try to explain it more clearly?

Comment: essentially the new menu, which is a 'megamenu' type, needs to be inside the top black bar (which can be changed, heights etc). It is placed in the right place according to the div layouts when you view the source however it seems to be overflowing and going into the wrong area?!

Comment: I understand now. @PeeHaa is correct: remove the whitespace between `<div id="menu-bar">` and `<div>` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `width: 930px;` somewhere.

Remove it.

```css
#topmenu {
    list-style: none;
    **width: 930px;**
    height: 20px;
    background: #014464;
    border: 1px solid #002232;
}
```

When I inspect the element (menu-bar) is see there are some space (like) characters outputted.

Comment: done that, however the menu itself is still sitting in the wrong place. it should be inplace of the black bar towards the top?!

Comment: Wayners247: Check out my updatted answer

Comment: well thats an interesting one, that didnt show up when I inspected it initially?! Thanks for spotting that!!